# SQL - calculate percentage that meet a criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that counts the number of customers in a country, and calculates what percentage of customers in each country satisfies a T/F condition. Additionally would like to be able to see if customers belong to multiple countries, if possible.

The table I am querying looks like:

```
Country     Cust_id     Condition
USA         3234        T
Mexico      7678        F
...         ...         ...
```

What I would like to produce:

```
Country    Count of Cust_id     Percent_Satisfies_Condition     Count_multiple_countries
USA        xx                   xx%                             xx
Mexico     xx                   xx%                             xx
...        ...                  ...                             ...
```

The "count_multiple_countries" would ideally provide a number of customers from that country that also have an entry belonging to another country. If this column isn't possible, still would like to know how to produce the first 3. Thank you!

Comment: Syntax and functionality can vary by vendor.  Please update the question tags to indicate which DBMS you're using, and which version #. Also, what have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: It would also help to see a slightly bigger data sample and the expected results *using that data sample*.  Showing actual values helps better illustrate the relationships in a way that dummy values (ie `xx` and `xx%`) do not.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Updated, thank you. Unfortunately I'm doing a written exercise (outside help/research is allowed and encouraged) so I can't actually test my solutions. What I have provided is all of the information I have on the hypothetical data table.

Comment: Tbh this site is more geared towards concrete programming issues, rather than hypotheticals. You'd probably have a better chance at an answer if you used a site like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 to build out your tables/data, try some queries, and then ask for feedback on why a particular query isn't working as expected.